# Working with camera in Android: Why is Cursor null when the picture is taken by camera and not selected from gallery?

Tags: android, image, camera, android-cursor

In my app the user can add many images either from camera or from gallery.
There is an addPhoto button on which the user clicks, she can select either camera or gallery, select or take a photo, and the photo is added to the page. And this can go on and on.

Every thing is working fine except for one thing: 
Some images are portrait and I need to rotate them (cause Android rotates them and makes them landscape and I have to rotate them back). But I can't do it with the camera pictures because the cursor is null for them.

The image is saved on the device. The Uri is not not. What else should I check? 
What am I doing wrong? What is weird is that when the image is selected from gallery every thing works perfect!

Here is the code for the Activity working with images:

```
public class CreatePropertyActivity5 extends ActionBarActivity {
    protected static final int SELECT_PICTURE = 1;
    private static final int ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE_IMAGE = 100;
    private static final int IMAGE_DESCRIPTION = 200;

    private static List<File> cameraImageFiles;
    private static Bitmap selectedImageBitmap;
    private static LinearLayout ll; 
    private static int id = 0;
    private static int password = 0;

    private static JSONRequestForCreatePropertyListing propertyListing;
    private static ImageView imageView;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_create_property_5);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

        //if not null, means Android has killed the process while the user has been working with camera or gallery to add images, and the onCreate is called AGAIN. And we don't want to initialize the layout again cause we will loose our previously added photos.
        if (propertyListing==null) {
            propertyListing = (JSONRequestForCreatePropertyListing) getIntent().getSerializableExtra("JSONRequestForCreatePropertyListing");
            CreatePropertListingAsync cplp = new CreatePropertListingAsync(this, propertyListing);
            cplp.execute();
            ll = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.llCreatePropertyImages);

        }
        else {
        //If Android has killed the activity once and this is the second time we are in onCreate(), the static ll which has the previously added images in it won't be attached to the xml page and so we have to add it manually.
            LinearLayout ll2 = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.ll_activity_create_property);
            ((ViewGroup)ll.getParent()).removeView(ll);
            ll2.addView(ll);
        }

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    }
    public void onClickTakePicture(View v) throws IOException {
        // Camera.
        final List<Intent> cameraIntents = new ArrayList<Intent>();
        final Intent captureIntent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);     
        final PackageManager packageManager = getPackageManager();
        final List<ResolveInfo> listCam = packageManager.queryIntentActivities(captureIntent, 0);

        cameraImageFiles = new ArrayList<File>();

        int i=0;
        for(ResolveInfo res : listCam) {
            final String packageName = res.activityInfo.packageName;
            final Intent intent = new Intent(captureIntent);
            intent.setComponent(new ComponentName(res.activityInfo.packageName, res.activityInfo.name));
            intent.setPackage(packageName);
            intent.putExtra(MediaStore.MEDIA_IGNORE_FILENAME, ".nomedia");

            //** below 4 lines put the uri of the camera taken picture to the EXTRA_OUTPUT 
            File cameraImageOutputFile = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES), "myFileName.jpg");
            cameraImageFiles.add(cameraImageOutputFile);
            intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(cameraImageFiles.get(i)));
            i++;

            cameraIntents.add(intent);
        }

        // Filesystem.
        final Intent galleryIntent = new Intent();
        galleryIntent.setType("image/*");
        galleryIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);

        // Chooser of filesystem options.
        final Intent chooserIntent = Intent.createChooser(galleryIntent, "add new");

        // Add the camera options.
        chooserIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INITIAL_INTENTS, cameraIntents.toArray(new Parcelable[]{}));
        startActivityForResult(chooserIntent, ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE_IMAGE);

    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent imageReturnedIntent)
    {

        switch(requestCode) { 

        // For sending photos to server. We come here from activity51 when user clicks on send photo. This "case" happens second. 
        case IMAGE_DESCRIPTION:
            if(resultCode == RESULT_OK){
                //add the image to the activity5 page.
                imageView = new ImageView(this);
                imageView.setPadding(0, 10, 0, 0);
                ll.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                if (findViewById(R.id.ll_create_property_successful)!= null)
                    findViewById(R.id.ll_create_property_successful).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                imageView.setImageBitmap(selectedImageBitmap);
                ll.addView(imageView);

                if ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.txt_property_listing_code)!= null)
                    ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.txt_property_listing_code)).setText(""+id);
                if ((TextView)findViewById(R.id.txt_property_listing_password)!= null)
                    ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.txt_property_listing_password)).setText(""+password);

                String s = imageReturnedIntent.getStringExtra("key");
                //user entered description is in "key"
                imageView.setTag(s);
                Bitmap bitmap1 = ((BitmapDrawable)imageView.getDrawable()).getBitmap();
                ByteArrayOutputStream stream=new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                bitmap1.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 90, stream);
                byte[] image=stream.toByteArray();
                String img_str = Base64.encodeToString(image, 0);

                //This part sends the picture to the server
                ArrayList<Photos> photos = new ArrayList<Photos>();
                photos.add(new Photos(new Ax(img_str)));


                //if not null, means Android has killed the process while the user has been working with camera or gallery to add images, and the onCreate is called AGAIN. And we don't want to initialize the layout again cause we will loose our previously added photos.
                JSONRequestForAddPhoto jr = new JSONRequestForAddPhoto(id, password, photos);

                new AddPhotoAsync(this, jr).execute();
            }

            //If user has pressed the cancel button and not the send photo button (in activity51) we come here and do nothing.
            break;
        //After the user has selected a photo (or taken one with camera) we come here :). This "case" happens first for a photo.
        case ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE_IMAGE:
            if(resultCode == RESULT_OK){

                Uri uri = null;
                if(imageReturnedIntent == null){   //since we used EXTRA_OUTPUT for camera, so it will be null

                    if (cameraImageFiles!=null && cameraImageFiles.get(0)!=null)    
                        for(int i=0;i<cameraImageFiles.size();i++){
                            if(cameraImageFiles.get(i).exists()){
                                uri = Uri.fromFile(cameraImageFiles.get(i));
                                break;
                            }
                        }
                    else
                        Toast.makeText(this, "Sorry :( A problem occured whille trying to add this photo", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                }
                else {  // from gallery
                    uri = imageReturnedIntent.getData();
                }

                if(uri != null){
                    try {

                        selectedImageBitmap = decodeSampledBitmapFromResource(uri, 500, 500);

                        Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
                        matrix.postRotate(getOrientation(this, uri));

                        selectedImageBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(selectedImageBitmap, 0, 0, selectedImageBitmap.getWidth(), selectedImageBitmap.getHeight(), matrix, true);


                        Intent i= new Intent(this, CreatePropertyActivity51.class);
                        i.putExtra("photoUri", uri);
                        startActivityForResult(i,IMAGE_DESCRIPTION);

                        //*** show activity51

                    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public Bitmap decodeSampledBitmapFromResource(Uri uri, int reqWidth, int reqHeight) throws IOException {

        ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();
        InputStream inStream = cr.openInputStream(uri);
        // First decode with inJustDecodeBounds=true to check dimensions
        BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
        BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inStream, null, options);

        options.inSampleSize = calculateInSampleSize(options, reqWidth, reqHeight);

        inStream.close();
        inStream = cr.openInputStream(uri);


        // Decode bitmap with inSampleSize set
        options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
        Bitmap result = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inStream, null , options);
        inStream.close();
        return result;
    }
    public int calculateInSampleSize( BitmapFactory.Options options, int reqWidth, int reqHeight) {
        // Raw height and width of image
        int height = options.outHeight;
        int width = options.outWidth;
        int inSampleSize = 1;

        if (height > reqHeight || width > reqWidth) {

            int halfHeight = height / 2;
            int halfWidth = width / 2;

            // Calculate the largest inSampleSize value that is a power of 2.
            while ((halfHeight / inSampleSize) > reqHeight     ||     (halfWidth / inSampleSize) > reqWidth) {
                inSampleSize *= 2;
            }
        }
        return inSampleSize;
    }

    public static int getOrientation(Context context, Uri photoUri) {
        /* it's on the external media. */
        Cursor cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(photoUri, new String[] { MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.ORIENTATION }, null, null, null);

        if (cursor == null)
            return 0;
        if (cursor.getCount() != 1) {
            return -1;
        }

        cursor.moveToFirst();
        return cursor.getInt(0);
    }


}
```

Answer (score 1):

When user picks image from *Gallery*, it returns a *projected URI* whereas in case of *Camera*, `URI` returned is a direct image path URI.

So, in case of **Gallery**, you do this,

```
/**
 * Get from library
 */
private void getPhoto() {
    Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,
            MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
    startActivityForResult(i, GET_PICTURE_REQUEST_CODE);
}
```

whereas in case of **Camera**, you do this,

```
/**
 * Take Photo
 */
private void takePhoto() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    //cameraImageUri is the Uri where camera app should save the clicked photo
    cameraImageUri = getOutputMediaFileUri(MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE);
    intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, cameraImageUri);
    startActivityForResult(intent, TAKE_PICTURE_REQUEST_CODE);
}
```

In `onActivityResult()`, in case of gallery, you neet to get the `imageUri` and get the cursor like,

```
String[] filePathColumn = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};
Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(imageUri,
              filePathColumn, null, null, null);
```

but in camera, you can directly use `cameraImageUri.toString()` to get the image path.

You do not have to convert that `direct URI` to a `projected URI` (which is obtained in case of gallery image pick).

To elaborate on difference between a `direct URI` and a `projected URI`, direct URI can look like `content://...` whereas a projected URI looks like `file://...` as it is obtained through a content resolver.

Comment: The camera stuff works like a charm! Thanks! Better explanation.